# Unable to recover CorelDraw File (.cdr)

Tags: coreldraw

I have the corel draw file which i tried to open but it is not opening, everytime a new blank page will create. Also I tried to recover using CDRRepairKit and RecoveryToolboxForCorelDraw, both are unable to recover my cdr file. Can anyone please suggest me any software to help with this...

If anyone can help me please comment your email id, so I can mail them the cdr file. Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried the following:

-Change the file extension to .ZIP

-open the zip file in WinZip

-In the file are these folders:

```
Color - contains color profiles used in the document

Content - contains file that you need to recover the document.

Metadata - contains xml files and thumbnails
```

-Extract the file called RiffData from the Content folder

-Open this file in CorelDraw.

http://howto.corel.com/en/c/How_To:_Recover_Corrupted_CDR_Files

Comment: yes Vuyk, I tried those steps also, but it is giving below error for all my files.
**The archive is either in unknown format or damaged**